# Running grunt sub task inside a custom module

Tags: gruntjs

I'm building a grunt module to help me to initialize, create default folder/files and build some WebProjects. I create a custom Grunt module including some custom tasks.

So My module is `oshell.grunt` and inside this module I've a task `InitializeLibrary`. This `InitializeLibrary` is a custom task that request some input from the user before creating the files/folder structure. I use `grunt-prompt` for this.

My problem is when I run the custom module inside my main project, the task `prompt` is not found. Can you please share your experience regarding this because I suppose some developers were faced to the same problem

Custom module structure

- oshell.grunt

  - tasks

    - InitializeLibrary.js

After installing the custom module inside the Main projects

- Main projects

  - oshell.core

    - node_modules
    - oshell.grunt

      - tasks

        - InitializeLibrary.js

It seems to be ok.

**InitializeLibrary.js**

```js
module.exports = function(
    grunt
){
    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({
        "prompt": {
            "libraryInfo": {
                options: {
                    questions: [
                        {
                            config: "InitializeOpenShellLibrary.version",
                            type: "input",
                            message: "Initial version of the library",
                            default: "0.1.0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    require("load-grunt-subtasks")(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask(
        "InitializeLibrary",
        [
            "prompt:libraryInfo"
        ]
    );
}
```

Main web project grunt file

```js
module.exports = function(
    grunt
){
    "use strict";

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("oshell.grunt");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["InitializeLibrary"]);
};
```

When I run this `grunt` in my main project I get this result.

> `Warning: Task "prompt:libraryInfo" not found. Use --force to continue.`

I expected the task `prompt` to run inside the custom module for having a prompt for the library information.

Thanks a lot for your answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

please install https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-prompt and add this code in grunt config file:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prompt');
```